# Create a Custom Control with the combination of multiple controls in WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I wish to create a Custom Control, it should be a combination of predefined controls like Textbox, Button, ListBox, etc.,

Kindly refer the following Controls (Just a Sample)

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Add" Margin="20,0" />
</Grid>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding textBox}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,25">
    <ListBoxItem />
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

I need a combination of controls in a single custom control. I need to add the Textbox values in a ListItem while I'm hitting the button and finally I need the List from this control.

Expected Custom Control (Just a Sample)

```
<cust:MultiControl ItemsSource="{Binding stringCollection}" />
```

**Description**:
I need to get the list of string from the user. I added a TextBox to get the input from the User. I added a Button to add the text in a `List<string>`. To display the List I added a ListBox.

I need a Single control, it should inherit these three controls. In that I need an `ItemsSource` for **two way binding**. If the `List<string>` is updated, it should update the ItemSource.

I'm using this structure in more than 15 places. So, I wish to make it as Custom control. Kindly assist me how to implement this as a single control ?

[image]

I don't need a User Control, I need a Custom Control kindly assist me...

Item Source ViewModel Collection is not updating even-though the ItemsSource has value.

[image]

Comment: A CustomControl is just a class that derives from Control. UserControl is also a class that derives from Control (indirectly), so a UserControl is a CustomControl. What's cool with UserControl is you can define them easily with a XAML file + code while a CustomControl is just code. So you really want a UserControl. You just need to add custom code to it, like DependencyProperties (for your exposed ItemSource) and custom logic.

Comment: Do you basically need an example of a working custom control? How to build one from scratch?

Comment: Please tell us, why dont you simply make a CustomControl? Whats your problem? If you know how to write a UserControl, there should be no problem writing a CustomControl... I Really dont get **what** you are asking for

Comment: @lokusking I need a control with structure as I mentioned in the question. In that I need a `ItemSource` attribute to bind the `List<string>`. The Control should take of all the functionality as I mentioned in the Question. You may have solution for my requirement in User-control means, then give your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've made you a minimal example of that desired CustomControl.

**The Control**

```
public class MyCustomControl : ItemsControl {

        static MyCustomControl() {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyCustomControl)));
        }

        private Button _addButton;
        private TextBox _textBox;
        private ListView _itemsView;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
            this._addButton = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_AddButton") as Button;
            this._textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;
            this._itemsView = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_ListBox") as ListView;

            this._addButton.Click += (sender, args) => {
                (this.ItemsSource as IList<string>).Add(this._textBox.Text);
            };
            this._itemsView.ItemsSource = this.ItemsSource;
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
        }

        public ICommand DeleteCommand => new RelayCommand(x => { (this.ItemsSource as IList<string>).Remove((string)x); });
    }
```

**The Template**

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Button x:Name="PART_AddButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="Add" Margin="20,0" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,25" x:Name="PART_ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                        <Button Content="X" Foreground="Red" 
                                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyCustomControl}}, Path=DeleteCommand}" 
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Margin="10,0,0,0"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**RelayCommand**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        #region Fields

        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

        #endregion // Fields

        #region Constructors

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        {
            if (execute == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

            this._execute = execute;
            this._canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region ICommand Members

        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this._canExecute == null || this._canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this._execute(parameter);
        }

        #endregion // ICommand Members
    }
```

**Usage**

```
 <local:MyCustomControl ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"/>
```

**Note**
Do not use a `List` as your ItemsSource. Rather use an `ObservableCollection` since it notifies the View automaticly and you dont have to deal with that Update-Stuff

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot... This is amazing, this is my actual expectation. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Thanks. I need an additional option to remove the Item from the List.

Comment: @IRPunch  Updated control with deleteButton

Comment: @lokusking - Thanks. But I need a delete Button within `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` each particular item I need a delete button to delete the Item.

Comment: @lokusking - I tried a Autocomplete Textbox with the same logic. I added one more dependency property `IEnumerable<dynamiic>` SuggestionItemSource. I binded the property in listbox. If I bind a `ObservableCollection<string>`, then it works perfectly, If i use `ObservableCollection <int>`, then it not works.

Comment: @lokusking - I changed the `(this.ItemsSource as IList<string>).Add(this._textBox.Text);` to `(this.ItemsSource as IList<object>).Add(this._textBox.Text);` itemsSource to not updating in ViewModel, but it updates in CustomControl. for the above example `ObservableCollection<string>`. kindly assist me.

Comment: @lokusking - Kindly refer the question I updated with new Screenshot at the bottom. How to notify the collection is changed when i add/remove from the ItemSource.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Please start a new question. This might get unreadable for others, if we are continuesly updating the question and answer

Comment: @lokusking - OK I post it in a new question. I'm seeking your guidance please.

Comment: @lokusking - I too faced the same issue. Kindly give your answer for the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187879/two-binding-issue-of-unknown-object-in-wpf-custom-control-dependency-property

Comment: @lokusking - Give you solution with Bounty points http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39187879/two-way-binding-issue-of-unknown-object-in-wpf-custom-control-dependency-propert

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this is your custom control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomControl.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<StackPanel Width="200" Margin="15">
    <TextBox  Name="txtbox"/>
    <Button  Content="Add"
            Margin="20,0"  Click="Button_Click"/>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             Margin="0,25">
    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>
```

And this is your Parentwindow Calling your custom control:

```
<Window x:Class="ParentControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ParentControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:customcontrol="clr-namespace:CustomControl;assembly=CustomControl"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <customcontrol:UserControl1 Name="customcontrol"></customcontrol:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

you have a string collection which you want to be updated with the text in the textbox, you can do something like this:
In the parent window set the DataContext of the custom control to the string collection, like this:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ObservableCollection<string> stringcollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        stringcollection.Add("String 1");
        stringcollection.Add("String 2");
        stringcollection.Add("String 2");
        stringcollection.Add("String 3");
        customcontrol.DataContext = stringcollection;

    }
```

and in your custom control back logic add handler to the button click event and do something like this:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var list = button.DataContext as ObservableCollection<string>;
        list.Add(this.txtbox.Text.ToString());
    }
```

make sure that the string collection is of Type Observable Collection, otherwise you listbox wont get updated everytime you click the add button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm expecting the solution in Custom Control not by UserControl. Thanks for your kind reply...

Comment: No. Its not a Custom Control. Just refer the Screenshot I apex-ed in the question block.

Comment: I need this as an independent control. If I implement user control means, its dependent on the project level (i.e., parent window level).