# Two-Way Binding Issue of Unknown Object in WPF Custom Control Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I'm having a Custom Control - Implemented for AutoComplete TextBox.
I got all idea's from the following question [Create a Custom Control with the combination of multiple controls in WPF C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842082/create-a-custom-control-with-the-combination-of-multiple-controls-in-wpf-c-sharp). In that Custom Control, they suggest the following code for adding item, **its perfectly working and the Two-Way Binding too**.

```
(this.ItemsSource as IList<string>).Add(this._textBox.Text);
```

But, I changed the following code to Unknown Object, so I changed `IList<string>` to `IList<object>`

```
(this.ItemsSource as IList<object>).Add(item);
```

XAML:

```
 <local:BTextBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
            ProviderCommand="{Binding AutoBTextCommand}" 
            AutoItemsSource="{Binding SuggCollection}" />
```

But it's not updating the ViewModel Property **`Collection`**. I too tried the following changes in the xaml

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

I don't know where I did the mistake.

**Functionality**: The `TextBox` inside the `CustomControl` takes the input from the User and it triggers the **`ProviderCommand`**, that Command filters the Remote data based on the User Input and sends the Filtered Collection via **`AutoItemsSource`**, this Property is binded as a `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` inside that `CustomControl` to select the Item. We can select the Item from the `ListBox` Item, by clicking the Item, it triggers the Command **`AddCommand`** which is in the `CustomControl` Class, it add the selected item in `ItemSource` Property of the `CustomControl`.  I'm having the **Two-Way Binding issue** in this Property **`ItemsSource`**. From this property only we may get the Selected item as a Collection.

Here is **my Complete Source Code**

The Custom Control C# Code:

```
public class BTextBox : ItemsControl
{

    static BTextBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BTextBox)));
    }

    #region Private Members
    private TextBox _textBox;
    private ItemsControl _itemsView;
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property Private Members
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProviderCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProviderCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AutoItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>), typeof(BTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceChanged));
    #endregion

    #region Dependency Property Public members
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> AutoItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<dynamic>)GetValue(AutoItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutoItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Listener Methods
    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = d as BTextBox;
        if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList<object>) != null))
        {
            (tb.AutoItemsSource as IList<object>).Add(e.NewValue);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Override Methods
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        this._textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;
        this._itemsView = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_ListBox") as ItemsControl;

        this._textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (this.ProviderCommand != null)
            {
                this.ProviderCommand.Execute(this._textBox.Text);
            }
        };

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
    #endregion


    #region Command
    public ICommand ProviderCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ProviderCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProviderCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegatingCommand((obj) =>
            {
                (this.ItemsSource as IList<object>).Add(obj);
            });
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The **Generic.xaml** Code is

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleControl">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BTextBox}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Row="0" Width="*" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding AutoItemsSource}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_ListBox_Sugg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value.IsChecked}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BTextBox}}, Path=AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Foreground="#404040">
                                            <CheckBox.Content>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Visibility="Visible"  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="270"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </CheckBox.Content>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The **MainWindow.xaml** Code is

```
<Window x:Class="SampleControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleControl" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:BTextBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" 
            ProviderCommand="{Binding AutoBTextCommand}" 
            AutoItemsSource="{Binding SuggCollection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The MainWindow.xaml's **Code Behind C# Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new StringModel();
    }
}
```

I'm having TWO ViewModels

**ViewModel #1 `StringModel`**

```
class StringModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> _suggCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private ObservableCollection<string> _primaryCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            _collection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> SuggCollection
    {
        get { return _suggCollection; }
        set
        {
            _suggCollection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SuggCollection"));
        }
    }

    public StringModel()
    {
        _primaryCollection = new ObservableCollection<string> { 
            "John", "Jack", "James", "Emma", "Peter"
        };
    }

    public ICommand AutoBTextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegatingCommand((obj) =>
            {
                Search(obj as string);
            });
        }
    }

    private void Search(string str)
    {
        SuggCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(_primaryCollection.Where(m => m.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(str.ToLowerInvariant())).Select(m => m));
    }

}
```

**ViewModel #2 `IntModel`**

```
class IntModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<int> _collection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    private ObservableCollection<int> _suggCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();
    private ObservableCollection<int> _primaryCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public ObservableCollection<int> Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            _collection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Collection"));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<int> SuggCollection
    {
        get { return _suggCollection; }
        set
        {
            _suggCollection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SuggCollection"));
        }
    }

    public IntModel()
    {
        _primaryCollection = new ObservableCollection<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                                                                11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 };
    }

    public ICommand AutoBTextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegatingCommand((obj) =>
            {
                Search(obj as string);
            });
        }
    }

    private void Search(string str)
    {
        int item = 0;
        int.TryParse(str, out item);
        SuggCollection = new ObservableCollection<int>(_primaryCollection.Where(m => m == item).Select(m => m));
    }

}
```

Comment: The short answer is that `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList<T>`, so only `ObservableCollection<object>` implements `IList<object>`, but in your case `T` is `string` or `int`. In both cases `ItemsSource as IList<object>` yields `null`. Normally, the way to proceed in such case is to cast the collection to non-generic `IList` interface (which `ObservableCollection<T>` implements), and which has an `Add(object)` method. But this code has several other problems to it that will prevent it from working (the `OnItemsSourceChanged` method in particular). I second the vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this post would have fitted better in CodeReview.

Second, i can imagine, what you did want to do.
To shorten things, i recommend you to **not** use generic collections in your case.

I've modified the Control a bit:

```
public class BTextBox : ItemsControl {

    static BTextBox() {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BTextBox)));
    }

    private TextBox _textBox;
    private ItemsControl _itemsView;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProviderCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProviderCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(BTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AutoItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(BTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsSourceChanged));

    public IEnumerable AutoItemsSource {
      get {
        return (IEnumerable)GetValue(AutoItemsSourceProperty);
      }
      set {
        SetValue(AutoItemsSourceProperty, value);
      }
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
      var tb = d as BTextBox;
      if ((e.NewValue != null) && ((tb.ItemsSource as IList) != null)) {
        foreach (var item in e.NewValue as IEnumerable) {
          (tb.AutoItemsSource as IList).Add(item);
        }

      }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate() {
      this._textBox = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_TextBox") as TextBox;
      this._itemsView = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_ListBox_Sugg") as ItemsControl;
      this._itemsView.ItemsSource = this.AutoItemsSource;
      this._textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) => {
        this.ProviderCommand?.Execute(this._textBox.Text);
      };

      base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }

    public ICommand ProviderCommand {
      get {
        return (ICommand) this.GetValue(ProviderCommandProperty);
      }
      set {
        this.SetValue(ProviderCommandProperty, value);
      }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand {
      get {
        return new RelayCommand(obj => {
          (this.ItemsSource as IList)?.Add(obj);
        });
      }
    }

  }
```

Then i've fixed your XAML to get thing to even compile and run:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:BTextBox}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Grid.Row="0"  VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding AutoItemsSource}" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_ListBox_Sugg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:BTextBox}}, Path=AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Foreground="#404040">
                                            <CheckBox.Content>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Visibility="Visible"  TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxWidth="270"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </CheckBox.Content>
                                        </CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

At last a valuable remark:

Never ever allow setters on your ItemsSources. If you override them, the binding will break. Use `.Clear()` and `.Add()` instead as you see below:

```
public class StringModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _suggCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _primaryCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Collection => this._collection;

    public ObservableCollection<string> SuggCollection => this._suggCollection;

    public StringModel() {
      this._primaryCollection.Add("John");
      this._primaryCollection.Add("Jack");
      this._primaryCollection.Add("James");
      this._primaryCollection.Add("Emma");
      this._primaryCollection.Add("Peter");
    }

    public ICommand AutoBTextCommand {
      get {
        return new RelayCommand(obj => {
          this.Search(obj as string);
        });
      }
    }

    private void Search(string str) {
      this.SuggCollection.Clear();
      foreach (var result in this._primaryCollection.Where(m => m.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(str.ToLowerInvariant())).Select(m => m)) {
        this.SuggCollection.Add(result);
      }

    }

  }
```

**Note**

Sice i didnt have your `DelegateCommand`-implementation, i've used my `RelayCommand` instead. You can change it withour any issues. I think its the same thing but a different name for it.
You also might consider to display your suggestions right from the start. This might provide a better user-expierience, but thats just my **opinion**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly assist me how to query in `(tb.AutoItemsSource as IList)` using LINQ ?

Comment: Sorry but i think i dont understand your question

Comment: Thanks, I need to bind a single item instead of List. Is there is any Interface like `IList` ? Kindly assist me...

Comment: If really want to bind just a single item you can use `object`. But tbh, i think that makes less sense. For a single item you dont need an `ItemsControl` or one of its derivations

Comment: I need one more help for the new question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462765/find-string-path-and-string-format-in-a-depedency-property-in-wpf-c-sharp

Comment: Kindly assist me, I'm facing NULL Reference issue, the question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505127/replace-null-with-a-default-value-in-an-itemssource-ienumerable