# Find List of binded property in a Depedency Property in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm having a WPF Custom Control

```
<local:SuperControl>
    <local:SuperControl.SBItem>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Name: {0} ({1})">
            <Binding Path="Name" />
            <Binding Path="ID" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </local:SuperControl.SBItem>
</local:SuperControl>
```

The ViewModel Property

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string ID { get; set; }
```

Consider the Value for the Property

```
Name = "John";
ID = "STK001";
```

The Custom Control

```
public class SuperControl : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SBItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SBItem", typeof(string), typeof(BAutoComplete), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string SBItem
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SBItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SBItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        string Name = SBItem;
        string ID = SBItem;
        string StringFormat = SBItem;
    }
}
```

Consider the Piece of Code in the Custom Control

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    string Name = SBItem;
    string ID = SBItem;
    string StringFormat = SBItem;
}
```

Here I need to get the **Value of the Binded Property** `Name`, `ID` and `String Format` from the **Dependency Property** `SBItem`. Kindly assist me.

Comment: I didn't completely understand you, are you trying to explode `SBItem` somehow...?

Comment: @AnnaSB, in runtime we don't know what type of string it is... So, I need to know the Binded information along with String Format...

Comment: Honestly, the question makes no sense. You can't have a dependency property of type string that is bound to a view model object via a MultiBinding (that produces a string) and hope to be able to access the single properties of the view model class.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan Will you pls explain whats your actual requirement.  What you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Clemens - Yes, you are right. If I trace the Binded information means it my reduce the complexity otherwise I need to register two more dependency property in the Custom Control to get the Values of Name and ID.

Comment: @Gopichandar - I explained my requirement above. My actual problem is different. Here I posted my piece of requirement, how to know the list of binded property in the specified Dependency Property simple.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan - Your question is valid.

Comment: @Clemens - How could I achieve this? kindly give your suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. It makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Clemens - I Clearly explained in my question how to fine the list of binded information in a Dependecy Property ? this is my question. I binded the ViewModel Property Name and ID in a Dependency Property. I way to find those information in code level. thats it.

Comment: @Clemens - don't think in your sense. Just think about the scenario which is given here and try to answer what we asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get Binded values in `ApplyTemplate` method. As it is called before binding.

So, provide a callback for property change using `new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged))` in your DP definition.

```
private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string value = (string)e.NewValue;
            string Name = value.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].Split(new char[] { '(' })[0].Trim();
            string ID = value.Split(new char[] { ':' })[1].Split(new char[] { '(' })[1].Split(new char[] { ')' })[0].Trim();
            string formatting = BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding(d, MyButton.MyPropertyProperty).StringFormat;
        }
```

Comment: `BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding` is the key here. Take the returned MultiBinding and iterate over its `Bindings` to check their `Path`.

Comment: He asked the question in general, but your answer is specific for the given string.

Answer (score 0):

As AnjumSKhan already stated, you have to implement a `Changed`-Method for the `DependencyProperty`. Following you'll find a more generic approach on how you can get the bound Values.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SBItemProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SBItem", typeof(string), typeof(BAutoComplete), new PropertyMetadata(Changed));

    private static void Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
      MultiBindingExpression mbe = null;
      try {
        mbe = BindingOperations.GetMultiBindingExpression(d, e.Property);
      } catch { }
      if (mbe != null) {
        foreach (var beb in mbe.BindingExpressions) {
          var bindingExpressionBase = (BindingExpression)beb;
          var di = bindingExpressionBase.DataItem;
          var p = di.GetType().GetProperty(bindingExpressionBase.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
          var val = p.GetValue(di);
          Console.WriteLine($"Property: {p.Name} Value: {val}");
        }
      } else {
        try {
          var binding = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(d, e.Property);
          var di = binding.DataItem;
          var p = di.GetType().GetProperty(binding.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
          var val = p.GetValue(di);
          Console.WriteLine($"Property: {e.Property.Name} Value: {val}");
        } catch {
          Console.WriteLine("No binding found");
        }
      }
    }
```

**Note**

Of course you have to replace my `Console.WriteLine` with your own logic. This example shall demonstrate, how you can get the values from the bound source. Probably you can ignore the part i've implemented as fallback if the Binding is a normal one and not a Multibinding.

Hope this gets you in the right direction