# WPF c# a button with a textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin.forms

I need to create a button similar like below, it is a textbox and a button combined, you can click "Get Code" button and you will receive a SMS text with the code, then you can input the code in the textbox.

[textbox and a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M17sm.jpg)

anyone can help?
Hi, my current code is quite simple.

```
<Button
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.Column="0"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Text="Get Code"
    FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }"
    Style="{ StaticResource CircleActionButtonFlatStyle }"
    micro:Message.Attach="[Event Clicked] = [Action SendVerifyCodeAsync()]"/>

<Entry
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    Text="{Binding Code}"
    Placeholder="Send Code" />
```

Comment: This would be a combination of a text box & button wrapped by a border.  You need to post your attempted WPF code before requesting help.

Comment: Also if you need help with sending SMS you have to show us what have you tried by showing us the code that you've already written. And then explaining what exactly is not working.

Comment: Hi Bizhan, the SMS function is working, I just don't know how to rewrite the xaml. Hi Jeff, I have edited my question and attached my current code

Comment: I think you have a good start. You need to wrap both controls with a rounded border. Check this out for some ways to do this: [wpf border with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120851/how-do-i-create-a-wpf-rounded-corner-container). You will probably need to create a button with rounded corners. If you search SO you should find ways to do this.

Comment: In order to combine the button and textbox into one control, you will need to create a  UserControl. Here is an example of creating and using a UserControl: [UserControl](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/usercontrols-and-customcontrols/creating-using-a-usercontrol/) or you can create the more feature rich but more complicated CustomControl.  An example is here: [CustomControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842082/create-a-custom-control-with-the-combination-of-multiple-controls-in-wpf-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Has people said in comments, you need to wrap it in borders. 
With this example, you just need to change the color for the ones you want, and then you can set Click events in the respective borders to make them act like buttons and do the respective actions. You can add the code `micro:Message.Attach="[Event Clicked] = [Action SendVerifyCodeAsync()]"` to the respective border.

Code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" CornerRadius="15">
        <Grid Margin="-1">
            <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Input code" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" CornerRadius="15" Background="#FF39D3D3">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Get Code" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0"/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Example:

[image]